# Voice Broadcasting With Multiple Asterisk For Large Call Volume

Tags: asterisk, voip, amqp, amazon-ami, broadcasting

How can I integrate AMQP to Asterisk AMI ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do something like that yourself if you have no at least 5 years REAL experience with asterisk.

You should check already developed solutions like vicidial.org and a2billing.org

Also asterisk on ec2 is very bad idea(perfomance/cost ratio is 10x more then on dedicated servers).

Comment: which language should be used for these application ?

Comment: Question to choose language, library etc is offtopic on SO.

Comment: I have done things like that and it is no simple task, it is difficult enough to get that working with vicidial for a "large call volume", at least what I would call a large call volume (multiple 100 calls at the same time).